# counting length of number and character inside string using regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, numbers, character

how to counting length of number and character inside string using regex in ruby?
if i have some case like this, how to resolve it?
example :

```
abc = "12345678a"
```

after counting using regex, i want get result like this :

```
number = 8
char = 1
```

how to do that?

Comment: how to get other way, besides regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following

```
abc = "12345678a"
abc.scan(/\d/).length
# => 8 
abc.scan(/\D/).length
# => 1
```

Comment: You don't need `join`.

Comment: Note that `scan(/\D/).length` gives you the number of characters that **aren't digits**, including spaces, new-line characters, punctuation, etc. This could very well be the desired behavior, just good to realize.

Comment: @funkwurm :- yeah, i forgot to mentioned it, +1

Answer (score 0):

No regex:

```
abc = "12345678a"
p abc.count("0-9") # => 8
p abc.count("a-zA-Z") # => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an optional, but I still think regex is better.

```
irb(main):051:0> number, char = abc.bytes.to_a.partition { |e| e >= 48 and e <= 57}
=> [[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56], [97]]
irb(main):053:0> number.count
=> 8
irb(main):054:0> char.count
=> 1
```

> partition: Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of enum for which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.